# Frigidaire Gas Oven High Pitched squeal

Tags: gas, oven

I have a Frigidaire LFGF3054TFE Gas Oven. When I use the oven there is a high-pitched squeal while gas is flowing.
My observations:

1. The high-pitched squeal does not occur when I use the burners.
2. The high-pitched squeal does not occur when I use the Broil setting.
3. I replaced the gas pressure regulator, but the high-pitched squeal is still occurring.
4. I pulled the oven away from the wall and turned it on. My thought was to straighten the flex pipe to reduce any turbulence. When the high-pitched squeal started, I turned the gas off at the valve, then turned it back on, and the squeal stopped. When I pushed the oven back and started it again the squeal returned.

It seems like the squeal is related only to the oven function. I'm going to try and adjust the lower shutter. Any other ideas?

**UPDATE**

Adjusting the lower shutter did not help.

Comment: Is there a sediment trap on your gas line?  It's possible that some gunk has partially clogged the venturi in the oven burner since that is the lowest point in the system.

Comment: This reminds me of another question where the noise is associated with the flame being in the wrong part of the burner.

Comment: This one: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/261803/18078

Comment: @ChrisO I think you are close - The safety valve [link](https://expresspartsdirect.com/products/316031501-erp) sits below the venturi and a small brass nipple is the gas outlet. I'm wondering if that needs to be adjusted. Closing and re-opening the gas valve stops the squealing. Something about that burst of gas when it's reopened.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I think I've removed turbulence/restriction from the list. If that were an issue then I would have the noise when I use the broiler or stove top burners. Unless the restriction is in the venturi or safety valve, but the venturi looks clear.

Comment: Normally there's an orifice per burner, so I don't see the other, different, burners as indicating that it couldn't be happening on the oven burner.

Comment: @Ecnerwal You're right, I don't think I explained it well. Some other posts point to the flex tubing as a poitn of turbulence/restriction. Thats what I was referring to, but your point is correct; there has to be an issue at the oven orifice.

Comment: at the back of the oven there is large air intake/supply opening. Rodent love it.

Comment: You can regulate the temperature of the oven, so turn it all the way down to change the gas flow rate

Answer (score 4):

I removed the brass nipple/orifice that the venturi and burner tube sits on. I cleaned off the connection, reapplied tape, and screwed it back on. The sound isn't present when I run the oven now. I guess cleaning and adjusting that brass orifice fixed it.

Comment: +1 points for coming back to report the fix

Answer (score 0):

It's the regulator. I know you've replaced the regulator. The new one is squealing just like the old one.

A gas regulator contains a diaphragm, a spring and a needle valve. When the outlet pressure against the diaphragm falls below the design pressure, which is set by the calibrated spring, the diaphragm allows the needle to withdraw slightly, admitting more gas and restoring the design pressure.

When pressure and flow are constant, the diaphragm and needle reach an equilibrium position that lets just enough gas through to maintain that pressure. But at one particular supply pressure and gas flow rate, any random vibration in the environment will cause the diaphragm to resonate at its natural frequency. While resonating, the needle is slightly opening and closing the valve, and the varying flow of gas reinforces the resonant vibration, prolonging it indefinitely.

Skeptical? If you can do so safely, light the oven, wait till the squeal starts, and then whack the regulator with a wooden spoon or some other object that will cause no damage. I think you'll hear the squeal pause for a moment, then resume.

The squeal is not caused by turbulence, a restriction or a bad jet. It's caused by having the bad luck to have a gas main pressure and oven jet flow rate that's exactly right to reinforce the resonant frequency of your regulator's diaphragm.

If you had an oven jet one size bigger or smaller, the regulator would not squeal, because the flow rate would be different. But changing jets is not a safe solution.

If you can find a different model of gas regulator with the same design pressure that fits in the available space -- presuming that it has a different size diaphragm -- it won't squeal.

Comment: `The high-pitched squeal does not occur when I use the burners.
The high-pitched squeal does not occur when I use the Broil setting.
I replaced the gas pressure regulator, but the high-pitched squeal is still occurring.` how come it only squels with oven

Comment: @Ruskes At the prevailing gas main line pressure, the oven jet uses the exact amount of gas required to make the regulator diaphragm resonate. Use more or less gas and the resonance is broken, so no squeal.

Comment: I appreciate this answer - I'm going to save it and if the sound starts to reoccur, I'll see if this works.

Comment: @Ruskes The four top corner burners are 17K, 5K, 9.5K and 14K BTU, total 45,500 BTU. The oven is 18,000 BTU. Your comment, now removed, said that you believe that 4 top burners and the broiler equal the oven. A comment expressing your belief without basis in fact is not useful. Again. And again. And again.

Comment: @Ruskes Downvotes should be reserved for answers that are not useful. Answers can still be useful to future readers even if the OP solves the problem another way. Read this troubleshooting report for a similar problem of a squealing regulator posted on airgas.com and then decide if the answer was not useful: https://www.airgas.com/resources/newsletters/cleanpeaks/2016/june/its-not-a-leak?_ga=2.265523023.1542412063.1674862962-1058152619.1674862962